# Return index position of links in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get an array of all links from a paragraphs innerHTML and store their start and end index, along with contents in comparison to the textContent.

```
<p id ="1">This is a <a href ="/hey">Link</a> and this is also a <a href="/hey">Link</a></p>
```

So for this I am trying to get something like:

```
//I know this is formatted weird, just showing an example of what data would like at end.
links = [
  'link1': { start_index: 11, end_index: 14, href: '/hey, text: 'Link'},
  'link2': { start_index: 35, end_index: 38, href: '/hey, text: 'Link'},
]
```

The start_index and end_index would be based on the links location in paragraphs textContent.

I have tried using indexOf()

```
str = document.getElementById("1").innerHTML;
var index_start = str.indexOf("<a href ="/hey">Link</a>");
```

But this would just return the index of the link in the innerHTML I am not sure how to get it's location in the textContent or how to get the location of all links.

Thanks and sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: What is the higher level use case here? Consider there could be other inline elements containing text also like `<span>` or `<strong>`. If there are what gets counted?

Comment: The contents will only ever have hrefs and it’s for sending data to the backend of where each link is located in the plaintext for PHP to then manipulate using the start and end index.

Comment: So you are saying there will never be other inline elements before the `<a>`? Still not very clear what you need this for

Comment: Correct only <a> elements. It’s for a very simple text editor that only deals with links and plaintext, and PHP needs to know their start and end index of where the link begins in textContent and not innerHTML as the server is only being sent textContent of the element.

Comment: OK...so first one is fairly easy but then do subsequent ones in same `<p>` need to account for the length of html for the first ones? This really sounds like an XY problem to me.

Comment: That’s where I am hung up too, not sure on how best to compare innerHTML and textContent and get all the link indexes of where they are in textContent.

Comment: What about putting placeholders in the text? Explaining the higher level use in more detail would probably help

Comment: hmm! Its gets trickier when there are two links in the same `p`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping It sure does!!

Comment: PHP is only sent the textContent of the paragraph. So it has no data of where the links are, hence it needing to be stored and sent with the data. But maybe I’ll coke back to this later when I can make a better example of what the backend etc is doing. Thanks

Comment: How is it going to get put back together (and why) later that you need the indexing. I'm sure there's an easier solution but still not clear what use case is all about. I am working on a concepts answer for you though

Comment: Put back together using substr_replace. Takes the index and other data to make the link, I’m better with PHP so that part works. As to the why: Because all the data is stored in json and can be rebuilt into HTML or any other format the data might be used such as wikitext, markdown, bbcode. PHP can take the json and build it. As it knows the paragraph contents, the indexes of the links, and the href and text of the link.

Comment: So I have a conceptual solution that replaces the links with a placeholder so text can easily be split at the placeholder. Seems to me you could do all that using a more robust placeholder like `[link text="foo" href="/somepath"]` and create a php parser for those. Similar to wordpress short code

Comment: I did think about that road, but using something like [link] means it's not visually represented as a link in the browser, where as I wanted user to not have to see any of that behind the scenes. Your post was extremely helpful.

Comment: Not in browser but to store in db. then you parse it based on where it needs to get output...like markdown, html etc. I think my approch can easily be developed further without the short code approach also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a starting conceptual solution.

It creates a clone of the `<p>` then replaces the links in that clone with a placeholder `||` which in turn allows for splitting the text string into array using that placeholder.

Then it maps the links into objects array and takes the preceding text length from the split text array (not from beginning of paragraph but from prior link for now).

With a bit more development it should be fairly easy to reverse engineer this to put the links back in the text

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p');

const txtArray = getTextInArray(p)

const links = Array.from(p.querySelectorAll('a')).map((el, i) => {
  return {
    href: el.href,
    linkTxt: el.textContent,
    prevTxtLength: txtArray[i].length
  }
})

console.log(links)


function getTextInArray(p) {
  let clone = p.cloneNode(true);
  clone.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => a.replaceWith('||'));
  return clone.textContent.split('||');
}
```

```html
<p>Some text <a href="foo">Foo</a> some more text <a href="boo">Boo</a></p>
```

Comment: So is this basically for a scraper?

Comment: A very basic simple text editor that does not allow for rich text other than links and then data to be stored in json to be used for anything else. But didn't want to bog down users with entering bbcode/wikitext/markdown so just a button that adds a link to the paragraph at your cursor position.

Comment: Well maybe my idea of spitting text into array is a way to save it also. Makes it easy to build it back if it's already stored in array

Comment: That’s a good point I didn’t think of. I was mostly thinking store the plain text and links separately. One to display the test just as text or just easily query for links in the text. Didn’t think of splitting the entire thing up. Text, link, text, link. That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @charlietfl Nice one mate!

Answer (score 2):

This was a little tricky to do, but i finally did it.

The following code worked for me, with your example.

```js
const str = document.getElementById('1')

const linksInStr = [...str.querySelectorAll('a')]

let strInnerHTML = str.innerHTML

const links = linksInStr.map((element) => {
  const urlProps = new URL(element.href)
  const el = `<a href="${urlProps.pathname}">${element.textContent}</a>`
  const start_index = strInnerHTML.indexOf(el)
  const end_index = start_index + element.textContent.length
  strInnerHTML = strInnerHTML.replace(el, element.textContent)

  return { start_index, end_index, href: urlProps.pathname, text: element.textContent }
})

console.log(links)
```

```html
<p id="1">This is a <a href="/hey">Link</a> and this is also a <a href="/hey2">Link2</a></p>
```

Please note that i had to change the href and the textContent of the second "a" element by adding a "2", because the method "indexOf" only returns the index of the first text that matches the search.

Comment: Looks good! Only hiccup I see is if text of link exists elsewhere in the paragraph text then getting indexOf could be off.

Comment: Hey, i modified the code a little to avoid that problem. Now it only matches the exact "a" element innerHTML instead of its textContent to avoid the problem with the IndexOf method.

Comment: I think it gets even trickier using html length to put it back together later. Not trying to nit-pick yours apart because it is an interesting exercise and  can clearly see you put good effort into a solution. Nice job

Comment: @N-bred Wao. Very Nice one. I was going to put through a similar looking solution but got busy with something!